# Free Group Theory and Free Profinite Group Theory Questions

Tags: gr.group-theory

Dear Experts,

1) Does someone know of any evaluation of the number of $p$-groups of order $p^n$ and rank $k$ ? (In particular, rank $2$? )

2) In the profinite group theory- we take a finitely generated free group $F$ , and denote by $S_f$ the interesection of all the normal subgroups $S \triangleleft F$  such that $F/S$ is a finite group.  Does the group $F/S_f$ have a name? (It arises when talking about profinite completions, so I guessed it must have a name)

thanks a lot for any help ! 
Karrol

Comment: The answer to 2 is the free group. 

Comment: This is residual finiteness of free groups. 

Comment: More generally, for any group G, the intersection of all the normal subgroups of finite index is sometimes called the 'finite residuum' of G.

Comment: I believe that 1 is totally intractable. 

Answer (score 4):

1-You may consider the function $f(n,p,c,d)$ which is the number of $p$-groups of order $p^n$ of class $c$ generated by at most $d$ generators. This function was studied by Marcus du Sautoy using the theory of zeta functions of groups. You can look at his paper
http://www.ams.org/journals/era/1999-05-16/S1079-6762-99-00069-4/S1079-6762-99-00069-4.pdf

Christopher Voll gives an explicit formula for this function when $c=d=2$. You can look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1355

Diego